# Error: unsafe value used in a resource URL context

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, youtube

I'm trying to put a youtube video on to show on my html page but I have this error
Error: unsafe value used in a resource URL context

in my code everything seems to be ok, I'm using pipe safe

```
  <div class="container"  *ngIf="!loading">
      <h3 class="title mb-3" >Vídeos</h3>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 py-3" *ngFor=" let video of item.config.videos">
          {{video}}<!-- https://www.youtube.com/embed/-fclle4fEuU-->
          <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
            <iframe  class="embed-responsive-item" src="{{video | safe}}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

the safe pipe

```
transform(url) {
return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With DomSanitizer you should use it like this:

```
[src]="video | safe"
```